# Fspy add-on not installing

Tags: add-on, import, fspy

I am continuously trying to install FSPY, but according to the instructions on the Github, it is clearly mentioned that **not to unzip** it.
[image]
 I tried it to import it as `File>Import>fspy`, but there is no option for FSPY...
I also tried to install the zip file from Blender(Install Addon)
[image]

Then how can I install it?
Any advice will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TLDR;** Download the latest release: https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases

---

Scroll down the [github page](https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender) and read the instructions on how to install the add-on properly:

1. Download the latest version from the [release page](https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases) (`fSpy-Blender-VersionNumber.zip`)
2. In Blender go to *Edit > User Preferences > Add-ons* and click *Install from File*
3. Select the `fSpy-Blender-VersionNumber.zip` file by using the file browser
4. Don't forget to *enable the Add-on*

If successfully enabled, a new menu entry in *File > Import* will appear:

[image]

---

#### **Don't** download the entire repository!

[image]

Again, download the latest release: https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases

Comment: Apologies for confusion re screenshot comment. Suggest in future posting the link to the addon source in question. IMO no need for screenshot proof of missing menu item.  If your question is in regards to 2.8 or prior,  for the time being might pay to flag in title.

Comment: Apologies my side too..✌

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the addon first.

For 2.79 Go to File > User Preferences > Add-ons and click the button in my screenshot and point the dialog box to the .zip file

[image]

For 2.8 Go to Edit > Preferences > Add-ons and click the same button and point the dialog box to the .zip file

[image]

EDIT: Then make sure the addon is enabled like so:

[image]

Then you can go to File > Import and you should be able to import your desired file type.

Comment: I didn't understand that how to point the dialog box to the zip file

Comment: Once you click "Install Addon from File" you will be able to navigate you your .zip file, once you do that the add-on will be installed.

Comment: I already did that, then to add-on is not showing in the list..

Comment: Apologies, I for some reason assumed you had installed addons before, so missed a step. I have edited my answer for you.

Comment: No you are getting it wrong, I had installed add-on previously like BLAM, it installed without any problems and it was by this method only to install it from blender itself but this(fspy) isn't installling, it may be installing but is not showing in the list to enable it..

Comment: Then i'm un-sure of how to help any further, I have done the exact steps in my answer (i did the steps from a blank Blender file to create my answer for you) and it's working fine for me, I have the ability to import fspy files with Blender 2.8

Comment: I don't know why it is not working for me..anyways thanks for your efforts..

Comment: It works well for me. Are you using the last 2.8 build ?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem with build 2.82. I can select the zip file, which then opens to show 2 additional folders, and the dialog wants to import again. Selecting one of the folders does nothing. The Import/Export does not display the Add-On, even after Refresh, or after closing/opening Blender.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download and Install FSpy Application for windows.
   (https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy/releases/download/v1.0.3/fspy-setup-1.0.3.exe)
2. Download FSpy Add-on for Blender.
   (https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases/download/v1.0.2/fSpy-Blender-1.0.2.zip)
3. Open Blender > Preferences > Add-ons > Install Add-on > Select the downloaded 'FSpy-Blender-1.0.2.zip'
4. Enable the add-on
5. Open the FSpy Windows client and Open a reference image. (tweak the perspective as necessary)
6. Save the "tweaked" image as .fspy"
7. Import the .fspy image and you're good to go

Answer (score 1):

I think that some of the confusion with installing the FSPY in Blender 2.8 is that at least for Safari users, the downloaded zipped files automatically get unzipped if they are deemed safe in Safari by default. You will need to turn that functionality off. Go to Safari Preferences > General > and uncheck Open "Safe Files" after download. Blender is looking for the unzipped file.

I did this, then downloaded the file, and it installed in Blender 2.8 no problem. Hope this helps.

-Todd

Comment: Actually, I hope that no one is using safari anymore :P

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run fspy on LINUX
 you need to download this link https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy/releases/download/v1.0.3/fspy-1.0.3-x86_64.AppImage and then open "downloads" or folder what you select to download
and click right on file named fspy.Then go to "properties" then "permisions" and click on "is executable".

I also downloaded this icon file file: https://fspy.io and click right on the logo and click "save image as" and select folder.Then click right on file named fspy.Then go to "general" then file type options and click on the icon image and browse the icon.

Answer (score 0):

I know normally how to install addons. None of the suggestions worked. Fspy does not appear in the list, but it exists in the scripts/addon folder. Whenever the reason will be found, I would be glad to know. Maybe use an older Blenderversion just for fspy...- very professional lol! - Greeez!