# Where is the fSPY .py script to add to Blender addons on Mac?

Tags: add-on, osx, fspy

I'm trying to import a scene into blender using the Mac version of fSPY. I don't see anything in package contents or the download page to import to Blender itself so that I can import fSPY files.

I've tried using the .dmg file, zipping it, zipping the windows file, digging through package contents for a .py file.

Edit: The answer referenced does not help. I am on a Mac, the answers are for Windows and Linux. Zipped .dmg files do not install into the addons folder of Blender. Installing blender addons on a Mac usually requires a .py file that you manually drag over to the addons folder inside of package contents inside the blender application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fspy add-on not installing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130532/fspy-add-on-not-installing)

Comment: Download link: https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases/download/v1.0.3/fSpy-Blender-1.0.3.zip Doesn't matter if you're on OSX, linux or windows. Add-ons are **always** python files (sometimes coming in a zip), **no dmg's**. Furher reading: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169234/how-to-download-and-install-an-add-on-hosted-on-github-properly/169235#169235